# Python multiple For loops with different delay

Tags: python-3.x

Im making a bot and need the script to perform multiple tasks with different cooldowns on each task. The tasks need to be repeated with different cooldowns.

Im new to programing and i have tried using for loops with range, but with the setup of the code it does the first task then waits out the cooldown of the first task rather than continuing on with another task then repeating the first one after it's cooldown. ATM it does the first task, waits the time.sleep then does the code in the loop under. But i want it do the second part of the code right away after the first task.

```py
    for i in range(1000, 3000):
        bot.krim()time.sleep(bot.krimcd)
        time.sleep(bot.krimcd)

    for j in range(1000, 3000):
        time.sleep(3)
        bot.bil()
        time.sleep(bot.bilcd)
```

the expected outcome is that it does the first task, waits 3 seconds, does the second task and When the time.sleep(bot.krimcd) is done it repeats the first task, and when time.sleep(bot.bilcd) is done it repeats the second task.

Comment: You probably want asynchronous programming, e.g. with the `asyncio` or `trio` modules. A `time.sleep()` call in Python suspends the program completely for the given amount of seconds, you can't (easily) do something else in the meantime.

Comment: thank you, im going to look into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my last answer was completely inaccurate, I was basing my answer off of a library I built for myself, thats entirely my bad, here:

This uses the `threading` module and creates threads for each function and runs them at the same time.

```
import threading

def func_name1():
    for i in range(1000, 3000):
        bot.krim()time.sleep(bot.krimcd)
        time.sleep(bot.krimcd)

def func_name2():
    for j in range(1000, 3000):
        time.sleep(3)
        bot.bil()
        time.sleep(bot.bilcd)

f1 = threading.Thread(target=func_name1)
f2 = threading.Thread(target=func_name2)
f1.start()
f2.start()
```

Comment: No problem at all :), if you could pick this as the answer so people know this is closed and I get my rep so I can help others better in the future, that would be great :D